# Multiple sensor data logging in Android

Tags: android, logging, sensors, android-sensors, datalog

I am working on a datalog application to log data of all the sensor's available on the android device. I wanted to know which is an efficient way? Registering a single listener for all the sensors or individual listeners to each sensor?

Thanks
Dheepak

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called Andro Sensor, with a possible addon AndroSensor Log Collector, which allows you to send the collected data to an email address. But unfortunatly it is not possible to send a periodically log file via email or to listen live to your android sensors from remote.